# multiple docker files in a directory

Tags: docker, yaml, docker-compose

I have multiple docker files in a directory. When I execute

```
docker-compose up
```

which `yaml` file will be executed?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

If you have a file named docker-compose.yml, it will be used,

Extract from

`docker-compose help`

you have

`Options:
  -f, --file FILE             Specify an alternate compose file (default: docker-compose.yml)`

so you can specify another file, something like

`docker-compose -f my_file.yml up`

Comment: what would happen if there is no docker-compose.yml and you only write 
    docker-compose up? for exampl, In my directory there are x.yaml, y.yaml and z.yaml and when I write docker-compose up some thing gets executed. I wonder if docker execute all of them or only one of them

Comment: you can execute them explicitely with `docker-compose -f x.yaml up` and so